# Нужно ли в предложении выражение out of stock ставить в кавычках?

Tags: кавычки

Для управления с ситуацией out of stock компания должна принять несколько мер.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я думаю, нет. Про такое, во-первых, нигде не говорится, во-вторых, названия, написанные латиницей, сами по себе являются выделительными, то есть дополнительное выделение (кавычками) не нужно:

***Для управления с ситуацией out of stock компания должна принять несколько мер***.

Answer (score 0):

Я счичаю, что да, так как, если их не ставить, всё не по-леопольдовски выглядит, т. е. по-непонятному-с.

`Для управления с ситуацией «out of stock» компания должна принять несколько мер.`